# Razor Components + EF Core + Repository/UoW Pattern changes entities without SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-components

I'm currently building a test app with Razor Components, Entity Framework Core and a few standard patterns (Repository Pattern, UnitOfWork). Changes in my entities are temporary saved (if i navigate through pages, the changes are visible) without calling `SaveChanges` in my UoW class (wrong). Refreshing the app removes those temp. changes - a call of my unit of work `Complete()` function saves changed data permanent (right).

I can't figure out why those temporary object changes are used/visible across my pages. The unit of work is (in general) working, because only calling `SaveChanges()` saves data for my app runtime). Current setup:

- VS 2019 Preview
- .NET Core v3.0.0-preview2 (because preview 3 doesn't work in combination with Windows 7 and Razor Components, issue already stated on GitHub)

Startup.cs - Adding the unit of work in my server startup

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

and adding the in-memory database context

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Database"));
```

DatabaseContext.cs

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {



        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.Entity<Customer>(ConfigureCustomer);

        }

        private void ConfigureCustomer(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
        {

            builder.ToTable("Customers");
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();

        }

    }
```

Repository.cs - repository implementation

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {

            Context = context;

        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);

        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            return await Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();

        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
        {

            return await Context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {

            return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();

        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);

        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);

        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().Update(entity);

        }


    }
```

CustomersRepository.cs

```
public class CustomersRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomersRepository
    {
        public CustomersRepository(DatabaseContext context) : base(context)
        {



        }

    }
```

UnitOfWork implementation

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {

        public ICustomersRepository Customers { get; private set; }

        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(DatabaseContext context)
        {

            _context = context;

            Customers = new CustomersRepository(_context);

        }

        public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
        {

            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

            _context.Dispose();

        }

    }
```

My customer entity

```
public class Customer
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }

    }
```

My test detail page

```
@page "/customers/{CustomerId:int}"

@using RazorApp.Core.Entities
@using RazorApp.Core.Interfaces

@inject IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork

<h1>Customer details</h1>

@if (customer == null)
{

    <p>Loading ...</p>

}
else
{

    <div class="card">

        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="card-text">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label>Id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@customer.Id" disabled />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label>Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@customer.Firstname" bind="customer.Firstname" />

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@UpdateCustomer">Save</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

}

@functions {

    [Parameter] int CustomerId { get; set; } = 0;

    Customer customer = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {

        await LoadCustomer(CustomerId);

    }

    protected async Task LoadCustomer(int customerId)
    {

        customer = null;
        customer = await UnitOfWork.Customers.GetAsync(customerId);

    }

    protected async void UpdateCustomer()
    {

        UnitOfWork.Customers.Update(customer);
        await UnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

    }

}
```

I expect that changes to the object (with data bindings or just regular changes like `customer.Firstname = "123"`) should only be saved if I call my UoW `Complete` function. I don't want any "cached/temporary/referenced" object updates across my application.

Comment: You've got some glaring issues, such as implementing `IDisposable` on your unit of work, and disposing of injected instances (huge no-no), but that shouldn't have anything to do with persistence. The behavior you describe screams that you're using something with a singleton lifetime, but I don't see anything where that's actually the case. It's possible this is due to using an in-memory database. I've only used that for integration testing, so persistence across requests isn't really an issue in such a scenario.

Comment: Hey Chris! My Code builds on Mosh's Repository and UoW tutorials. I'm not that experienced in .net - so thank's for your hints! I really appreciate that. If anything else is really bad or just bad practice, please say it. And yeah, i don't use any singletons ... i just don't get it, that my entities are updated without calling any saving methods :/

Comment: It may be a function of the in-memory database. It's really not intended for this purpose; it's only for testing. If you want a lightweight database to actually run against, you can use SQLite.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I'll try that out. But regarding the `IDisposable` - many tutorials, people and books are suggesting the UoW Dispose of the DbContext - what is (in your opinion) a better way? Thanks again, i really appreciate your time.

Comment: It's not about what people recommend/better ways. It has to do with whether or not your object owns resources or not. Since you're injecting the context, the object doesn't own that. In fact, the DI container is the owner, and it and it alone is responsible for disposing it. Your object should only dispose of things it owns.

Comment: Hey @ChrisPratt - i tried running my app with SqlServer (instead of testing it with the in-memory database) and exactly the same stills happens. UoW savings are working and persistent, but only any changes to the entities (without calling SaveChanges()) are still globally set during app runtime. I'm out of ideads :( I also tried different things (like `services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();` or testing without the UoW and only with the repository) without any luck :(